# How to use gitversion on older codebase

Tags: semantic-versioning, gitversion

I tried running gitVersion on extremely old and complicated codebase that was migrated with git-tfs. I do get results in most branches but they are incorrect.

1. How do I get started with existing repositories?
2. How do I debug the results so I know what contributed to the final output?
3. Can some branches be ignored because they used are incorrectly attributing a larger number?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that you are having issues using GitVersion.

1. Not sure what you mean here, can you elaborate?
2. The GitVersion log output is quite verbose, as you can see [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cakebuild/cake/build/0.15.0-PullRequest.1098+73.build.2426#L859) as an example.  It walks you through what base versions it can locate, and from there, how it asserted the final version number.
3. You might want to take a look at the `commits-before` [configuration option](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/) which might help with an older code base that wasn't sticking to conventions, and a result, ignore the prior commit history, and start versioning a fresh.